# mongoose schema дополнительный параметр с ObjectId

Tags: mongoose

Мне нужно вставить дополнительный параметр "цена" в схему "Товара" для каждого отдельно Размера".

Как это сделать?

Схема **Товар**:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    sizes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'size'
    }]
})
```

Схема **Размер**

```
const sizeSchema = new Schema({
    title: String
})
```

Answer (score 0):

При создании размера задавай сразу цену,таким образом в схеме товара в поле sizes у тебя будет список размеров сразу с ценами, или дай больше информации если не то.

```
const sizeSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
price:Number
})
```

Comment: Цена у размеров товаров разная, а в предложенном Вами варианте цена будет одинаковой для всех размеров. т.е. у одного товара с размером XL цена 500 руб, а у второго товара с тем же размером XL цена 800 руб.

Comment: ну дак если у тебя для каждого товара для каждого размера уникальные цены, и нет никакой формулы расчета цены товара в зависимости от размера, придется тебе значит прописывать каждую вручную для этого не нужна отдельная коллекция, можно прям в товаре сделать объект со свойствами-размерами а значениями-ценами

Comment: Согласен. Хотел реализовать что то типа LEFT JOIN. Видимо не выйдет. Спасибо.